# Is there any advantage of using MEMM instead of CRF for named-entity recognition?

Tags: natural-language, maximum-entropy, conditional-random-field, named-entity-recognition, memm

I wonder whether there is any advantage of using [maximum-entropy Markov model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum-entropy_Markov_model) (MEMM), a.k.a. conditional Markov model (CMM) instead of using [conditional random fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field) (CRF) for named-entity recognition, aside from the training cost.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think MEMM has advantage over CRF. MEMM still have label bias issue while CRF not.